# Сервер отсылает дубликаты данных всем клиентам WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

Код был полностью взят с [источника](https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets#%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80) и редактирован 1 файл.

```
Server.js
```

```
var http = require('http');
var Static = require('node-static');
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');
var rand = 0; 
var rTime = 0;
var sTime = 0;
var count = 0, timer = 1;
var clients = {};

function rec () {
    var Interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(timer == 20) { timer = 0;
            clearInterval(Interval);
            startRoll();
            var Timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                clearTimeout(Timeout);
                timer = 0;
                rec();
            }, 5000);
        }else { if(timer"Знак меньше"20){timer++;}}
    }, 1000);
} rec();

function startRoll () {
    rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    rTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1501) + 3000;
    sTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 100;
}

// WebSocket-сервер на порту 8081
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({port: 8081});
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws) {
  var id = count++;
  clients[id] = ws;
  console.log("новое соединение " + id);

    ws.on('message', function() {
        for (var key in clients) {
          clients[key].send(timer + "|" + rand + "|" + rTime + "|" + sTime);
        }
        rand = 0; rTime = 0; sTime = 0;
    });

  ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('соединение закрыто ' + id);
    delete clients[id];
  });

});


// обычный сервер (статика) на порту 8080
var fileServer = new Static.Server('.');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  fileServer.serve(req, res);

}).listen(8080);

console.log("Сервер запущен на портах 8080, 8081");
```

Создан обработчик script.js

```
var rand,
rTime,
sTime;

if (!window.WebSocket) {
    document.body.innerHTML = 'WebSocket в этом браузере не поддерживается.';
}

// создать подключение
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081");

// обработчик входящих сообщений


function rec() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        socket.send("return");
        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        var incomingMessage = event.data;
        $(".top_links").html(incomingMessage);
            incomingMessage = incomingMessage.split("|");
        var timer = incomingMessage[0];
            rand  = incomingMessage[1];
            rTime = incomingMessage[2];
            sTime = incomingMessage[3];
            if (timer == 0) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                startRoll();
            }else{
                 $('#spaner').text(timer);
            }
        };
    }, 1000);
} rec();
```

Это все для прокрутки рулетки. Параметры которые присылает сервер это номер выигравшего билета, время прокрутки и время прокрутки до остановки (своя система ))

Колесо крутится первый раз, а потом не понятно от чего это зависит от 1 до 4-5 раз.Обычно в `$(".top_links").html(incomingMessage);` выводится строка типа 5|0|0|0 а после истечения 20 секунд отправляются данные выигрыша, 0|3|4000|300
А тогда когда происходит сбой, сразу после этих данных появляется 0|0|0|0. Я ни как не могу понять с чем это связано.

Все работает, но есть один нюанс. Если открыть страницу `index.html` в нескольких вкладках, сообщения на обе будут дублироваться столько же раз сколько открыто вкладок.

Вот пример.

```
19|0|0|0
19|0|0|0
20|0|0|0
20|0|0|0
```

Предполагаю это из-за цикла `for`, но если от него избавится и заменить все client[id] на ws - cmd ругается и говорит ошибка.

Собственно вопрос, как у всем клиентам, независимо от их количества показать 1 сообщение ? (В файле browser.js слушаю сервер 1 раз в секунду. Пользователь не участвует в отправке данных).

Как поступить, господа ?

Comment: Все правильно, как написанно так и работает. Укажите в вопросе желаемого повеление.

Comment: @korytoff Дописал.

Comment: Надо смотреть серверную часть

Comment: Эх блин на дату не посмотрел :(

Answer (score 3):

Внутри цикла `for` переменная цикла `key` не используется. Это так называемый "запах кода", обычно такая ситуация - ошибочна.

Кстати, в приведенном вами источнике тело цикла написано правильно.

Comment: После "Експеримента" не вернул в прежнюю форму. Исправил. Но проблема не в этом.

Answer (score 0):

когда у тебя два пользователя или более сидят,то они в двоем или более отправляют сообщение,и значит запускается два цикла или более одновременно(+-300мс) for

Решение 1:

заменить

```
for (var key in clients) {
    clients[key].send(timer + "|" + rand + "|" + rTime + "|" + sTime);
}
```

на это

```
ws.send(timer + "|" + rand + "|" + rTime + "|" + sTime);
```

т.е. уйти от цикла

Решение 2:

объявляем глобальную переменную

```
  var lastTimeSend = 0;
```

затем в on message сделать следущее

```
  ...
    if(lastTimeSend !=timer){
              for (var key in clients) {
                clients[key].send(timer + "|" + rand + "|" + rTime + "|" + sTime);
              }
            rand = 0; rTime = 0; sTime = 0;
            lastTimeSend = timer;
          }
```

Решение 3: игнорировать сообщение пользователей

```
function rec () {
    var Interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(timer == 20) { timer = 0;
            clearInterval(Interval);
            startRoll();
            var Timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                clearTimeout(Timeout);
                timer = 0;
                rec();
            }, 5000);
        }else { if(timer<20){timer++;}}


        for (var key in clients) {
          clients[key].send(timer + "|" + rand + "|" + rTime + "|" + sTime);
        }
      rand = 0; rTime = 0; sTime = 0;


    }, 1000);
} rec();
```